# deleteNode deletes the node in front of it

Tags: c, linked-list

```
void deleteNode(charNode *pNode) {
    struct charNode *temp;
    temp = pNode->next;
    pNode->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}//deleteNode
```

above is a function in C that deletes a node. However, it deletes the next node. How do would I delete the node given in the parameter?

Comment: You need to call it with the previous node

Comment: when i call it withe previous node what then would I have to do with it?

Comment: Two things: head of list is a special case.  Tail of list is the other special case.

Comment: *"when i call it withe previous node what then would I have to do with it?"*: nothing? What do you mean? You need to pass the preceding node, as otherwise you have no way to rewire your list correctly.

Comment: You cannot delete a node without knowing the node prior to it. That's the node that holds a pointer to it. Just pass this function the node before the one you want to delete.

Comment: If you want to be able to delete a node given only a pointer to that node, you need to implement a doubly linked list.